# How to use ViewState after Request.Form?

Tags: c#, postback, viewstate, request.form

Hi I'm  trying to save the values from the request.form after post back.  I've tried to use viewstate on the input string but the page_load keeps regenerating the request.form

```
string TID = null;
Protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (TID == null)
     {  
            TID= Request.Form ["totalID"];
      }
      Label1.Text = TID;
}

protected void Button2_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Label1.Text = TID;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most asp.net controls have a text property, so if yours is a `TextBox` and you named it textBoxTotalID, then you can just get the value entered using `this.textBoxTotalID.Text`.

Instead of `totalID`, use the name of the element not the Id. The name is used for posting information to the server. And also make sure you have specified a name in your view for the element whose value you need on post.

In addition to that, ask yourself this question: Do you need to do that even when the user requests the page or only when the form is submitted? I am sure your answer is only when form is submitted. In that case, do it only when `IsPostBack` is `true`.

Comment: Did you change your view? Let me see the code for your view please.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a check to the `IsPostBack` property.

```
if (IsPostBack)
{
    //Set Values here
}
```

This is set to `true` when the page is responding to a post back from a form submit or perhaps a control event being fired.

Comment: That will not solve his problem but what you are saying is correct. Therefore, it should be a comment so the OP can improve his code. If you had made a comment, I would have upvoted because it is a good comment. But not a good answer.

Comment: Hello, I tried to add a comment but being new to this site.. it didn't let me...said my reputation wasn't high enough :(